# Spring Social Twitter Save Data to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, twitter, spring-data-jpa, spring-social-twitter

I'm trying to save some data from the request I made against TwitterAPI. I jknow, that i have to set the objects I want in the UpdateTweetsService Class but I have now idea how i parse them. This is what I have so far:

UpdateTweetsService.java Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Tweet;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter;
import java.util.List;


public class UpdateTweetsService {@Value("${screenName}")
private final Twitter twitter;

@Inject
public UpdateTweetsService(Twitter twitter) {
    this.twitter = twitter;

}
/**
 * Performs a Request to get the UserTimeline from Twitter API
 */

 public List<Tweet> tweets() {

        return twitter.timelineOperations().getUserTimeline("${screenName}");    
 }
```

Tweet.java Class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tweets")
public class Tweet {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT unsigned")
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 255)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String profileImageUrl;

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 64)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(64)", length = 64, nullable = false)
    private String fromUser;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 255)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(columnDefinition = "FLOAT")
    private Float createDate;

    /*
     * Getter & Setter
     */

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProfileImageUrl() {
        return profileImageUrl;
    }

    public void setProfileImageUrl(String profileImageUrl) {
        this.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;
    }

    public String getFromUser() {
        return fromUser;
    }

    public void setFromUser(String fromUser) {
        this.fromUser = fromUser;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Float getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Float createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data JPA to save your entities. Its very easy to setup your database with Spring Boot.

You can checkout the code in my [Github](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/tree/dataJpa) repo, I updated it for this. I have used `PostgreSql`, you can easily change it to `MySql` by updating `pom.xml` and `application.properties` file as per below steps.

You need to follow below steps:

1. Add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `mysql` dependencies in your pom.xml

   ```
   .....
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.6</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Set the database config/properties in your `application.properties`

   ```
   .....
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
   spring.jpa.show-sql=true
   spring.jpa.database=mysql       
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
   spring.datasource.name=sakila
   spring.datasource.username=mysql
   spring.datasource.password=password
   ```
3. Create an Entity class `TweetEntity` which you already did, but rename it from `Tweet` to something else to avoid confusion between your `Tweet.class` and `org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Tweet.class`
4. Create Spring Data JPA Repositories interface for your entity.

   ```
   package com.rawsanj.tweet.repository;

   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

   import com.rawsanj.tweet.entity.TweetEntity;

   /**
    * Spring Data JPA repository for the User entity.
    */
   public interface TweetZRepository extends JpaRepository<TweetEntity, Long> {

   }
   ```

   Just be defining above Spring Data Repository you get several methods (like `save(Entity entity)`, `findOne(Long Id)`, etc) already implemented.
5. Let SpringBoot know your repository package, i.e. enable Jparepositories.

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableJpaRepositories("com.rawsanj.tweet.repository")
   public class Application {
   ....
   ..
   ```
6. And finally update your `Controller`:

   ```
   package com.rawsanj.tweet.controller;
   ....
   import com.rawsanj.tweet.entity.TweetEntity;
   import com.rawsanj.tweet.repository.TweetZRepository ;

   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/")
   public class HelloController {

       private TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate;
       private TweetZRepository tweetZRepository ;

       @Inject
       public HelloController(StreamService streamService, TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate, TweetZRepository tweetZRepository ) {
           this.streamService = streamService;
           this.twitterTemplate=twitterTemplate;
           this.tweetZRepository =tweetZRepository ;
       }

       @RequestMapping(value = "tweet/{search}/{count}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
       public String searchTwitter(Model model, @PathVariable String search, @PathVariable int count) {
           SearchResults results = twitterTemplate.searchOperations().search(
                   new SearchParameters(search)
                       .resultType(SearchParameters.ResultType.RECENT)
                       .count(count));

           List<Tweet> tweets = results.getTweets();        
           model.addAttribute("tweets", tweets);

           for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {            
               TweetEntity tweetEntity = new TweetEntity(tweet.getText(), tweet.getCreatedAt(), tweet.getFromUser(), tweet.getLanguageCode(), tweet.getLanguageCode());
               tweetZRepository.save(tweetEntity);
           }
           return "search";
       }
   }
   ```